# css changes not getting reflected

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');

:root{
    --main-color: #8e44ad;
    --black: #222;
    --white: #fff;
    --light-black: #777;
    --light-white: #fff9;
    --dark-bg:rgba(0,0,.7);
    --light-bg: #eee;
    --border: .1rem solid var(--black);
    --box-shadow:0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    --text-shadow:0 1.5rem 3rem rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none; border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
html::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 1rem;
}
html::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background-color: var(--white);
}
html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color: var(--main-color);
}
section{
    padding: 5rem 10%;
}
```

```html
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>home</title>

        <!--swiper css link-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper-bundle.min.css">

        <!-- font awesome cdn link-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">

        <!-- custom css file link-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=<?=$version?>">
       
    </head>
    <body>
    <section class="packeges">
            <h1 class="heading-title">our packages</h1>
            <div class="box-container">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-6.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-7.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-8.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-9.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-10.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-11.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/img-12.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>adventure & tour</h3>
                        <p>Do some adventures and go to tours and enjoy yourself</p>
                        <a href="book.php" class="btn">book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="load-more"><a href="package.php" class="btn"> load more</a></div>
        </section>
        <!--swiper js link -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

        <!-- custom js file link-->
        <script src="js/script.js?v=<?=$version?>"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> I have made changes in my css file but that changes are not reflecting in my web page but if i apply same changes in browser console then the chages are applied.
> What will be the problem?

I have made changes in my css file but that changes are not reflecting in my web page but if i apply same changes in browser console then the chages are applied.
What will be the problem?
this is my css code

```
.packages .box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap: 2rem;
}
.packages .box-container .box{
    border: var(--black);
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
    background: var(--white);
}
.packages .box-container .box .image{
    height: 25rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.packages .box-container .box .image img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
 }
 .packages .box-container .box .content{
    padding: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.packages .box-container .box .content h3{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: var(--black);
}
.packages .box-container .box .content p{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: var(--light-black);
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 1rem 0;
}
.packages .load-more{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a cache problem. Ctrl+F5 will help.

Comment: Or Keep the browser's developer tools open and disable the cache in its network tab.

Comment: Can you give us full code with html, and make it like code snippet that we can run it and see

Comment: If your using vs code, right click on the css file and click on select "relative path option" and compare the file path with the one you have linked

Comment: path is correct

Answer (score 0):

To clear cache:

For **Win** `CTRL+SHIFT+R`

For **MacOS** `COMMAND+SHIFT+R`

To disable cache you can do something like this (if you are using php)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path-to-file/style.css?ver=<?php echo time()?>"  />
```

Dynamic GET paramether `ver` will make link different on every browser refresh

**-- UPDATE --**

After you updated the question you have typo in your code

```
    <section class="packeges">
```

You wrote `packEges` and in your .css is `packAges`

Comment: it didn't work i tried it

Comment: @SuneelKumarAnkavarapu in browser when you direct open the `.css` file did you see changes that you made?

Comment: the code is visible when i open view page source.

Comment: @SuneelKumarAnkavarapu If changes are visible inside `.css`, there are no reason that changes are not applied to site (with cleared cache). Did you tried private/incognito window or different browser?

Comment: i tried different browsers but it's not working . what will be the solution if the changes are not visible. And one more thing if i add the same code in my browser console then the css changes are reflecting

Comment: @SuneelKumarAnkavarapu I updated my answer according to your question update, hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't check for the name mistake. Now it's working. Once again thank you for spending time on my prolem.

Comment: No problem, any time :)

Comment: @user22148437 you can than mark this as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the given css file path is correct or not, in your HTML page Inside Head tag

Comment: i had given correct path